# duplicate list is adding to gridview in android

Tags: android, gridview

Hi in the below I am displaying calendarview.In calendarview I am selecting date and passing that date to GetAppointmentDate(selecteddate) if selecteddate and my date matches I am displaying gridview layout.but it is give multiple list with below .

Can any one help y duplicate list is displaying evrytime.

CalendarViewActivity.java:

```
public class CalendarViewActivity extends Activity implements DatetimeAdapter.MyItemClickListener{

    private CalendarView mCalendarView;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog = null;
    private ArrayList<GetData> getDataArrayList;
    private ArrayList<GetSlots> getSlotsArrayList;
    private GridView gridLayout;
    private  GetData getData2;
    private GetSlots getSlots2;
    private String Id,StartTime,SlotBooked,SlotDate,EndTime,SloteTime;
    private DatetimeAdapter datetimeAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.calendar_view);
        gridLayout=findViewById(R.id.gridlayout);
        getDataArrayList=new ArrayList<>();
        getSlotsArrayList=new ArrayList<>();

        mCalendarView = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
        mCalendarView.setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
        datetimeAdapter = new DatetimeAdapter(getApplicationContext(), getSlotsArrayList,this);



        mCalendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            int year1 = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month1 = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int dayOfMonth1 = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            @Override
            public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView CalendarView, int year1, int month1, int dayOfMonth1) {

                String date = new SimpleDateFormat("MM", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(date);

                String selecteddate = (sdf.format(month1 + 1)) + "/" + dayOfMonth1 + "/" + year1;

                GetAppointmentDate(selecteddate);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),selecteddate,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
        });


    }
    private void GetAppointmentDate(String outputcurrentdate) {
//        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getApplicationContext());
//        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
//        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
//        progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
//        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
//        progressDialog.show();
        String doctor_ids="13";
        String HospitalId="PH:193";
        final APIService service = RetroClass.getRetrofitInstance().create(APIService.class);
        Call<GetAppointmentDateModel> call = service.GetAppointmentDate(doctor_ids,HospitalId);
        Log.wtf("URL Called", call.request().url() + "");
        call.enqueue(new Callback<GetAppointmentDateModel>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<GetAppointmentDateModel> call, Response<GetAppointmentDateModel> response) {
                Log.e("response", new Gson().toJson(response.body()));
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.e("response", new Gson().toJson(response.body()));
                    GetAppointmentDateModel getAppointmentDateModel = response.body();
                    ArrayList<GetData> getData = getAppointmentDateModel.getGetAppointmentList();
                    for (GetData getData1 : getData) {
                        String date1 = getData1.getDate();
                        String id=getData1.getId();
                        DateFormat inputFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm-HH:mm");
                        Date date = null;
                        try {
                            date = inputFormatter.parse(date1);
                            DateFormat outputFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
                            String output = outputFormatter.format(date);
                            getData2=new GetData(id,output);
                            getDataArrayList.add(getData2);
                            Log.d("dateString",output);
                            ArrayList<GetSlots> getSlots = getData1.getData();
                            for (GetSlots getSlots1 : getSlots) {
                                Id=getSlots1.getId();
                                SlotDate=getSlots1.getDate();
                                StartTime=getSlots1.getStartTime();
                               EndTime=getSlots1.getEndTime();
                                SloteTime=getSlots1.getSlotTime();
                                SlotBooked=getSlots1.getSlotBooked();

                                getSlots2=new GetSlots(Id,SlotDate,StartTime,EndTime,SlotBooked,SloteTime);
                                getSlotsArrayList.add(getSlots2);

                            }

                        } catch (ParseException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                    String current_date=getData2.getDate();
                    if(current_date.equals(outputcurrentdate)) {
                        gridLayout.setAdapter(datetimeAdapter);
                        datetimeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }

               // progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<GetAppointmentDateModel> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("error", t.getMessage());
              //  progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });



    }

    @Override
    public void myItemClick(int position) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Your list - getSlotsArrayList is addding new values each time and it is not clearing anywhere. This is the same list that is passed to the adapter. so it is displaying multiple values.

Comment: where to clear my getSlotsArrayList

Comment: Can you please edit my code helps me a lot

Comment: @PriyankaRajput I didnt get any answer for your side

Comment: Try to clear this list before GetAppointmentDate(selecteddate) method

Comment: getSlotsArrayList.clear()GetAppointmentDate(selecteddate) you mean to say like this?

Comment: Yes, Did it worked?

Comment: yes.............................

Comment: Great. I am adding answer with same. Kindly accept my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your list - getSlotsArrayList is addding new values each time and it is not clearing anywhere. This is the same list that is passed to the adapter. so it is displaying multiple values.

Call clear method before this

```
getSlotsArrayList.clear();
GetAppointmentDate(selecteddate);
```